# Cocoa Interface Design Question

Tags: nstableview, nscollectionview

The best thing for the window I'm designing would be a table with two rows for each element of an array.  I'd have one checkbox and two popups in the first row and the second row would be used for text entry.  Based on what I understand of a NSTableView is that's not possible.  I looked into a NSCollectionView but I don't have any experience with that so my choices are a standard four-column table or tackle a NSCollectionView.  Before I do that I wanted to get the opinions of more experienced Cocoa developers.

Thanks

Comment: Which part of that do you think isn't possible?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to make an NSTableView with two rows/record.  Is it?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using either an NSTableview or an NSCollectionview. The NSTableview way would be to subclass NSTextfieldCell ... take a look at ImagePreviewCell.m in apple's PhotoSearch example.

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/samplecode/PhotoSearch/

The NSCollectionview way would require less code (you can set just about all of it up in IB), but an NSTableView has stuff (like headers etc) than an NSCollectionview doesn't.